# Does Redshift optimize inter-block search or just scans the whole block?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I created two tables with `43,547,563` rows each:

```
CREATE TABLE metrics_compressed (
    some_id bigint ENCODE ZSTD,
    some_value varchar(200) ENCODE ZSTD distkey,
    ...,
    some_timestamp bigint ENCODE ZSTD,
    ...,
    PRIMARY KEY (some_id, some_timestamp, some_value)
)
sortkey (some_id, some_timestamp);
```

The second one is exactly like the first one but without any column compressed.

Running this query (it just counts one row):

```
select count(*)
from metrics_compressed
where some_id = 20906 
and some_timestamp = 1475679898584;
```

shows a table scan of `42,394,071` rows (from the `rows_pre_filter` column in `svl_query_summary`, column `is_rrscan` true) and  while running it over the uncompressed table it scans `3,143,856`. I guess the reason for this is that the compressed one uses less 1MB blocks, hence the scan shows the total number of rows from the retrieved blocks.

Are the scanned rows a sign of bad performance? Or does Redshift use some kind of binary search within a block for such simple queries as this one, and the scanned rows is just confusing info for optimizing queries?

Comment: The first sign of a bad performance is the execution time of the queries, how do they differ, if they do at all? In general it is not recommended to compress sort keys, probably due to problem that you guessed about (more rows in a block, longer time to search within a block).

Comment: The query over the compressed table takes twice the time. We have some complex queries taking much longer, and they're also retrieving 3M to count a few rows. We just wonder if there's something else to optimize regarding compression or keys, but we need to understand how it handles retrieving so many rows by block. Maybe Redshift is better used to count millions of rows and not just a few.

Comment: Then I think the answer is no, Redshift doesn't optimize the inter-block searches. Since it's a column storage that is just similar to sorting an array probably, where an array is a chunk of data for one column in a block. Compressing sort key is not a good practice since you'll be searching much larger array.

Comment: Can you please provide the output that shows it is scanning a different number of "rows"? Are you referring to the *cost* calculation in EXPLAIN TABLE output? More information please!

Comment: ^^ I see that data from svl_query_summary table for that query. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should **let Amazon Redshift determine its own compression types**. It does this by loading 100,000 rows and determining the optimal compression type to use for each column based on this sample data. It then drops those rows and restarts the load. This happens automatically when a table is first loaded if there is no compression type specified on the columns.

The `SORTKEY` is more important for fast queries than compression, because it allows Redshift to totally skip over blocks that do not contain desired data. In your example, using `some_id` within the `WHERE` clause allows it to only look at blocks containing that specific value and since it is also the SORTKEY this will be extremely efficient.

Once a block is identified as *potentially* containing the SORTKEY data, Redshift will read the block from disk and process the contents.

The general rule is to **use DISTKEY for columns most used in JOIN** and **use SORTKEY for columns most used in WHERE statements** (but there are also more subtle variations on those general rules).

Comment: Thanks, John. My question was specific to the case you just described. "Once a block is identified as potentially containing the SORTKEY data, Redshift will read the block from disk and process the contents". And then? What kind of optimization does Redshift provide once it has the potential block? Does it sequentially scan it?

Comment: I don't know what it does *within* a block, but apparently it reads in other blocks needed for the results (that is, storage blocks containing the other columns related to the block read). This can lead to problems when the primary block is highly compressed (containing lots of rows) because it has to read potentially many other blocks to load the same number of rows. This is why they often recommend not compressing the DISTKEY, because it leads to too many other blocks being read. I wouldn't be too worried about within-block efficiency as it is in RAM and only 1MB in size.